# Stopped BitLocker at 83% because it froze for 6 hours without making any progress, now when I unlock the drive everything freezes

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I stopped BitLocker at 83% because it froze for 6 hours without making any progress, then did a reboot. Now the drive D: has locked icon - I unlock it - prompts me with a modal for adding the password and it gets unlocked... Then everything freezes!

I tried: `manage-bde -unlock D: -Password` with CMD, I input the password and it says 'successfully unlocked'. This way nothing freezes. But when I open MyPC (win+E) it loads really slowly, after it loads in a minute I can go to D: - right click - Manage BitLocker - and then I waited for 1 whole hour - the BitLocker page in Control Panel is loading - it has only the titles of the 3 sections - drive C:, drive D:... but nothing under them.

I tried `manage-bde -status D:` but it freezes on this:

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I tried `manage-bde -off D:` but it freezes on the exact same line about Copyright.

When I try to open D: the File Explorer crashes with Not Responding and I can't kill the task, so only reboot fixes this.

The drive is 1TB HDD and I don't have anything else to back it up on it.

Comment: If an IO operation freezes usually the used disc drive is defect and causing long delays for every read/write operation (e.g. 30 seconds for each operation wich normally takes less than a second, hence it looks "frozen" to you). Therefore you should boot a different OS from USB-stick/DVD and check the used HDD SMART values for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Recovery may be possible. You would need:

- The password, recovery password or the recovery key for the encrypted volume
- A volume with at least as much free space as the partially encrypted volume

The command to run is:

```
repair-bde encrypted-drive-letter: empty-drive-letter: -password
```

You will be asked for your password to proceed.
The decryption will probably get stuck at the same point as the encryption
(83%), so hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> at the command prompt to
interrupt the process.

If all went well, between the two drives you will have recovered most of
your data. The next time, take backups *before* using Bitlocker.

Comment: +1 for making backups *before* attempting encryption (or any format change to a drive).

Comment: Okay, I will try. Got myself an external drive and I will try to recover it on the other drive. I hope it won't freeze on the Copyright line in cmd like manage-bde. I will mark it as an answer if it works, could take a day or two. Thanks for the suggestion